# How can I add a "Library Project" in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm using ActionBarSherlock in an Android project that I developed using Eclipse. I'd like to migrate that project over to IntelliJ IDEA, but I'm not sure how to add a "Library Project" to IDEA.

Is this a feature IDEA supports? If so, can someone help me figure out how to add one?

Thanks!

**UPDATED:** What I'm referring to is what they describe here -- [Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject). They allow you to add a reference to an uncompiled project as a "library."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create a new IDEA module from the existing source code. Ensure that Android facet is enabled for this module, in the facet settings you need to enable "**Is Library Project**" option. Then add this module as a dependency to your main module.

Comment: Can you elaborate the last sentence "Then add this module as a dependency to your main module."? What did you mean with it?

Comment: @sandalone: see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html for details.

Answer (score 9):

For new visitors:

Create a module from existing sources (point to the library directory inside ABS), then add android-support-v4.jar as a dependency to your project and ABS modules.

There's also a detailed [tutorial](http://android-wtf.com/2012/09/how-to-configure-actionbarsherlock-with-intellij-idea/).

Comment: Also for newer visitors: ABS 4.4 doesn't have a 'library' sub-folder anymore, so you will just point to the base 'actionbarsherlock' folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dependency on another module in IntelliJ.

You can import the existing Eclipse project into IntelliJ.

You can add libraries to a module in IntelliJ.

I'm not clear on exactly what you want to do.  Can you add info to your question?

Answer (score 0):

First Remove that library then add Library project 
as a module ,add Module as a dependency