# Can not include source library in project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, library-project

I've created library project in IDEA with **common helpers**, which I use in my android applications.

Then I've created android application and included in it my library project like [this tutorial said](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Everything seemed okay, code autocomplete worked fine, IDEA recognize that library and all classes and methods in it.

But then I compiled application and saw error "**'org.my.helperlibrary' does not exist**". However as I said IDEA acts like everything okay before making/launching project.

[Here is similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884662/how-can-i-add-a-library-project-in-intellij-idea), but answer is trivial, of course my library has checked "**Is Library Project**" option but I still can not launch my application which use my library.

**Updated:**

I've just saw an error: "**UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/my/helperlibrary/Helper;**" when I removed all usages of library in my android application. So it's just included in my app and not used.

Comment: Are the helpers a library project or jar files ?

Comment: Helpers are java classes in library project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I should not add dependency manually in that window

[image]

I rather should add new module in my Project window at the left

[image]
[image]
[image]

Then I should choose **iml** file in the root folder of android library project I want to use

[image]

Then I pressed finish and from that point I had two modules in my project

[image]

After that when using classes I can press Alt+Enter on any class from SampleLibrary and tell IDEA to add module dependency

[image]

Then I could see that IDEA made all I need without me. I can now use SampleLibrary from SampleApplication!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to select library project, then click `Build -> Compile <your library project name>`.
Then back to you project which use this library and click `Build -> Rebuild Project`.
After that try to run project again.

Hope it helps.