# How to import apklib into Android Studio or IntelliJ project?

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, android-studio, apklib

I have another Android project contains res, src, AndroidManifest.xml and project.properties and has been package into apklib.

How can I use it in my main project. I am using IntelliJ and Android Studio, after I open File > Project Structure, it seen can only import jar file. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using maven ?

Comment: I think this question has been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884662/how-can-i-add-a-library-project-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 1):

I want to answer my own question after I found out recently. If we have module B need module A library.

apklib is create as a library and can be use and read from maven to reference. So if set module A in maven's pom.xml dependency, when mvn build it will ask maven to look for apklib.

And as IntelliJ and Android Studio, just go to project structure set the module to Android Library, and add module dependency, then like module B can use from module A.