# Android : How do I use the ActionBarSherlock on older versions of Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm beginning development on an app and I set the target to Android 2.2. can i use actionbarsherlock in my app?

I added below code in pom file :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>r7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

but my app does not run in my phone with android 2.2 and i have this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
```

In this case what am i doing?

when i set `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"` in AndroidManifest.xml appear this error:

Android Resource Packaging: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock').

Comment: You should use one of suggested theme, just set theme name in AndroidManifest.xml  Also you should look at appcompat project - this is google replacement of ABS

Comment: i complete my guestion.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update the theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
```

Comment: when i set android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" in AndroidManifest.xml appear this error:

Android Resource Packaging: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock').

Answer (score 1):

To use ActionBar in API levels lower than that, you can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this attribute to your application tag in Manifest file `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"`

The library should be added as reference to be able to use the Sherlock Theme. For adding the library in IntelliJ check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884662/how-can-i-add-a-library-project-in-intellij-idea) out:

Comment: when i set android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" in AndroidManifest.xml appear this error:

Android Resource Packaging: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock').

Comment: try adding `<type>apklib</type>` in your sherlock dependency

Comment: how can i add actionbarsherlock as a refrence?where?

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `android:theme` as `@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` or any other sherlock style inside your `application` tag in `AndroidManifest` file

Comment: when i set android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" in AndroidManifest.xml appear this error:

Android Resource Packaging: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock').

Comment: Did u add the sherlock actionbar library into your project?

Comment: No, i did not add it into my project, should be add?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should download actionbarsherlock from the [website.](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) I have no idea how to import it in IntelliJ, but maybe you can import your project in eclipse IDE (download it on the official site if you don't have one) then import actionbarsherlock to Eclipse, add it as a library to your app, then after configuring it, import the project again to IntelliJ.